# SQL Server Concatenate Certain Subsquent Rows onto Parent Row Using Set-Based Solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to parse a BAIv2 banking file in t-SQL after importing to a table. The file is composed of rows and each row has two leading numbers. If the leading number for a row happens to be "88", it's a "continuation row" and is meant to be an extension of the previous row (to prevent the rows from getting too wide in the file). Example file below:

> 01,123456,123456,123456,1419,1,80,,2/
>   02,123456,123456,1,123456,,USD,2/
>   03,123456,USD,010,0,,,015,0,,,020,0,,,025,0,,,030,0,,,040,0,,,045,0,,/
>   88,050,0,,,055,0,,,057,0,,,060,0,,,072,0,,,074,0,,,100,123456,1,,270,123456,1,/
>   88,400,123456,35,,470,123456,35,/
>   16,275,123456,S,123456,0,0,,/
>   88,ZBA XFER FROM BANK ACCOUNT   123456
>   16,475,123456,Z,123456,123456/
>   88,CHECK-IRD
>   16,475,123456,Z,123456,123456/
>   88,CHECK-IRD

How do I used a set-based SQL query to append the rows with a leading "88" to the previous row? It looks like an XML based query might work. I was able to accomplish this with complicated loops and variables but it's very inefficient so I'd like a set-based solution. Any help would be appreciated.

I need it to look like this with the "88" records appended to previous rows:

> 01,123456,123456,123456,1419,1,80,,2/
>   02,123456,123456,1,123456,,USD,2/
>   03,123456,USD,010,0,,,015,0,,,020,0,,,025,0,,,030,0,,,040,0,,,045,0,,,050,0,,,055,0,,,057,0,,,...
>   16,275,123456,S,123456,0,0,,,ZBA XFER FROM BANK ACCOUNT   123456
>   16,475,123456,Z,123456,123456,CHECK-IRD
>   16,475,123456,Z,123456,123456,CHECK-IRD

Comment: How is the table set up at the  moment?

Comment: It just has an id column and a column called text_record to hold the rows from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if you have a consecutive `int` ID column in your table

**EDIT** rewritten as recursive CTE. probably there is an easier way, but it runs:

```
;with x (ID,txt,lvl)as 
(select ID,cast(txt as varchar(max)),1 as lvl
from @table
where ID = 1
union all
select a.ID
,cast((case when left(a.txt,2) = '88' then cast(b.txt AS varchar(max)) else '' end)+ a.txt as varchar(max))
,case when left(a.txt,2) = '88' then b.lvl else b.lvl + 1 end
from @table a
inner join x b on a.ID = b.ID + 1)

,y as (
select *,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY lvl ORDER BY LEN(txt) desc) as rnk from x
)

select ID,REPLACE(REPLACE(txt,'/',''),'88,','') as txt from y where rnk = 1
```

Comment: This is sooo close but for the 03 record it doesn't appear to be appending the second 88 record of: 88,400,123456,35,,470,123456,35,/

Comment: There can be more than one continuation record for any parent record.

Comment: @JordanRovny check the edits. I ran it and it worked

Comment: That worked. Just need to make a few more tweaks but I think that pretty much did it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LEAD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) or [LAG()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) windowed functions to peek the prior or next record. A CTE would make this a bit easier on the eyes but I had started down the other way already.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Value NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT @Test SELECT 1,'111,111,111,111'
INSERT @Test SELECT 2,'222,222,222,222'
INSERT @Test SELECT 3,'88,222,222,222,222'
INSERT @Test SELECT 4,'333,333,333,333'
INSERT @Test SELECT 5,'88,333,333,333,333'
INSERT @Test SELECT 6,'88,333,333,333,333'
INSERT @Test SELECT 7,'444,444,444,444,444'
INSERT @Test SELECT 8,'555,555,555,555,555'


SELECT
    Value=MAX(Value)    
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ContinuationGroup,
        Value=SUBSTRING((
            SELECT
                ','+Value
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ID,Value,ContinuationGroup=SUM(ContinuationGroup) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN 99999 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)       
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT  
                        ID, Value= REPLACE(Value,'88,',''), ContinuationGroup=CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('88,',Value) >0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END   
                    FROM
                        @Test               
                )AS A       
            )AS B
            WHERE 
                B.ContinuationGroup=Y.ContinuationGroup
            ORDER BY ID FOR XML PATH( '' )
        ), 3, 1000 )    
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Value,ContinuationGroup=SUM(ContinuationGroup) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN 99999 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)      
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  
                ID,Value= REPLACE(Value,'88,',''),ContinuationGroup=CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('88,',Value) >0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END   
            FROM
                @Test

        )AS Z
    )AS Y
)AS X
GROUP BY
    ContinuationGroup
```

Comment: This is also very close but what about the second "88" record? There can be more than one continuation record for any parent record.

Comment: I see Added a SUBSTRING(... FOR XML PATH( '' ) ) For concatenation

Comment: I tried running this but it runs for longer than 30 seconds. I'm still trying it out.